# Spring @Value field is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have problem with @Value annotation in Spring, i'm trying set field from properties file. My configuration applicationContext.xml is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/local/*.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

properties file is in src/main/resources/config/local/general.properties

General properties

```
general.key="EDC183ADVARTT"
```

And in my class i want to inject field from this file.
My class

```
import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher; import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;

import org.postgresql.util.Base64; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; 
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@javax.persistence.Converter 
@Component 
public class EntityEncryptionConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    @Value("${general.key}")
    private String keyCode;

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final byte[] KEY = "395DEADE4D23DD92".getBytes();

    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String ccNumber) {
        System.out.print(keyCode);
        // do some encryption
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return Base64.encodeBytes(c.doFinal(ccNumber.getBytes()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        // do some decryption
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES");
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(c.doFinal(Base64.decode(dbData)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Why my value of KeyCode is null ?

Comment: @Value("{general.key'}")
private String keyCode; - why do you have ' after key?

Comment: soorry , i tried a lot of things and i forgot delete this. now its ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the EntityEncryptionConverter bean in the same Spring context as the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?  Post processors only decorate beans in the same context.

**Edit**

As we discussed, the EntityEncryptionConverter instance you're getting in JPA is not the Spring managed instance created by Spring's component scan.  Thus, no value set on keyCode.

I think you have a few choices here, none of which I find very "clean".

1. Don't use Spring to get keyCode value in the Converter.  In the Converter, read the keyCode value from a properties file old school via Java Properties.
2. You want to use Spring, ok...  Then create an Application Context aware Converter.  You could create an AppContext provider as described [here](http://blog.jdevelop.eu/?p=154).  With that provider you could either look up the keyCode in Spring (may have to expose it as a String bean) or you could look up the EntityEncryptionConverter instance that Spring is managing, then delegate the converter methods to that instance.

Comment: what you mean ? something like that <bean id="entityEnctyptionConverter" class="entity.converter.EntityEncryptionConverter"/>

Comment: Is the component-scan for the package that contains EntityEncryptionConverter in your applicationContext.xml?  Or is it in, say a dispatch servlet context?

Comment: Or asked a different way, how your component scanning configured to load EntityEncryptionConverter?

Comment: Next question:  How are you expecting JPA to get the bean out of the Spring context that has your key value set on it?  JPA doesn't know anything about the Component bean that Spring is going to configure with your value.  JPA is just going to construct a new instance of your Converter.

Comment: Steve ,i think that my problem is in Transaction entity, because im using annotation like a  `@NotAudited
 @CreditCardNumber
 @Convert(converter = EntityEncryptionConverter.class)

 private String cardNumber;`
and this is new instance. Do you have any idea how to fix it ??
@value annotation is working in another classes

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<value>classpath:config/local/*.properties</value>
```

should be:

```
 <value>classpath:*.properties</value>
```

Comment: i have more properties in config/local , i cant change this, i have there db.properties , mail.properties and this working fine.

Comment: @Murder Is the coverter autowired in other classes?

Comment: im using this class for encryption and decryption , like "@NotAudited
 @CreditCardNumber
 @Convert(converter = EntityEncryptionConverter.class)
 private String cardNumber;"

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo on the Value with an extra '

```
@Value("{general.key'}")
```

Should be:

```
@Value("{general.key}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

```
@Value("#{general['general.key']}")
```

Comment: I got this error  Property or field 'general' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?

Comment: No, it should inject into private property as well. Try remove double quotes in your property file. `general.key=EDC183ADVARTT`  it is not necessary.

Comment: I removed and is still the same situation :)